# Command for inequality of char

Tags: java

I want to ask the user about whether he wants to continue playing or not. For this I have used,

```
 char choice; 
 do
 {
      System.out.println("Would you like to continue?(y/n)");
      choice=sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
      if (choice!='y' && choice!='n')  
      {  
           System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
      }
 }while (choice!='y' && choice!='n');
```

This is working fine and I didn't face any issues, but is that the right way?

Comment: did you run it? what issues you face?

Comment: I didn't face any issues. I was just asking, is that the right way?

Comment: Are you asking for entire code / logic or some specific lines?  Again, are you able run program as per your requirement?

Comment: If it meets your requirements, then it is in some sense the right way. It may not do exactly what you want, since the user could enter `"yabbadabbadoo!"`, which would be interpreted as `'y'`; whether that is a problem is up to you.

Comment: @Andy Turner as per your point that IS a problem according to me since I want to make my programs 100% efficient. Then, how can I solve it?

Comment: Your way isn't wrong at all. :P The fact is, programming has a bazillion "right ways" to do something. This is one of them. Might want to take it to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Qix what I mean by 'right way' is I wanted to know if it's efficient; and as per the point mentioned by Andy Turner, I think it's not right. Any 'better' way?

Comment: @Shinjinee Maiti Stop lying (to yourself).  You do not want to make your program 100% efficient; you are using java not assembler or c.  Kudos on the do-while though.

Comment: @DwB I am here to get an answer to my question and not to indulge in some kind of philosophical discussion on whether I am 'lying to myself' or not. And as to the term '100% efficient', I hope you understand that it means as much efficient as possible. Thanks for the appreciation though. And I apologize if I seem to be too rude.